# WCF connection with HTTPS security using SSON cookie

Tags: c#, wcf, cookies, https

I have little experience with cookies so i need some help here.

I have a scenario where i have to establish WCF connection to the remote endpoint using the **https** security. The situation is complicated by the thing that endpoint address in client config is actually pointing to a web **proxy** which redirects request to the actual endpoint if SSON auth has been detected or redirects to auth page.

**Example**: service address for client config is 'https://a.com/my.svc'. If auth is OK i will connect to this address, if not, i will be redirected to 'https://a.com/auth' and after successful auth will proceed again to 'https://a.com/my.svc'

If i open the address in the Web Browser i'm redirected to auth page and after successful auth (login/pwd) then redirected to the address. After the authenication the SSON cookie is generated and all consequent address queries lead me straight to the address with no additional auth.

As of now i've done the following:

1. Do auth using WPF **WebBrowser** control. I've got the cookie after that.
2. Made client endpoint connection. Yeah the session is used by default in prod environment, i'm not sure if i can remove it.

   ```
   <customBinding>
   <binding name="WSHttpsBinding_IDB2Connector">
     <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="23:59:59" ordered="True"/>
     <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="false" />
   </binding>
   ```
3. Direct connection works fine. I mean i don't connect to proxy address but use final endpoint address instead and don't use cookies.

Now the problem is how i can made my WCF connection to use SSON coookie to bypass auth page on **ClientBase.Open** call?

Comment: I'm not sure is this ever possible/ I can play with msg headers but only when connection is already established. And the problem is that i can't establish the connection without the cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have SSO cookie from auth form you can use OperationContextScope to send HTTP headers.

```
YourServiceClient client = new YourServiceClient();
using(new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel)) 
{
    // Add a HTTP Header to an outgoing request
    HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    requestMessage.Headers["Cookie"] = "MySSOCookie=MySSOCookieValue"; //SSOCookie content
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;

   client.doSomething();

}
```